# OpenCart Custom fields in email confirmation

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module, opencart2.3

I set up some custom fields which appear in Checkout page. Everything works perfect, but the email confirmation don't include those custom field.

Can you help me with a solution?

I use OpenCart  2.3.0.2

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this modification.

https://github.com/opencartbrasil/exibir-campos-personalizados